# How can i access on Tick function of a countDownTimer in my viewmodel in my ui screen

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

i have a countdowntimer in my viewmodel like this

```
  fun startTimer() {

        stopAllTimers()
        _isRunning.value = true
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(duration, INTERVAL) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                _remainingTime.value = millisUntilFinished / 1000
            }

            override fun onFinish() {}

        }.start()
    }
```

now i want to play a sound when timer ticks so in ontick i want mediaplayer that starts

i know it's a bad practice to have context inside viewmodel for my viewmodel so whats the best way i can access the onTick function in my ui or maybe other workarounds?

Comment: Expose the data you want from ViewModel using observables like Flow, LiveData, RxJava, etc and observe them in the UI to do necessary actions.

Comment: yes i can do that i already have access to _remainingTime.value as flow in my ui i dont know how it will help me play sound "mediaPlayer.start()" onTick though

Comment: Use Compose Effects to play the sound when the data changes. LaunchedEffect can be used or DisposableEffect if required.

Comment: ok will try the launched effect with _remainingTime.value to play the sound and disposable effect to release the mediaPlayer thanks!

Comment: You can use AndroidViewModel so you have access to the `Application`, from which you can use its leakproof `context`. Although a MediaPlayer can be thought of as a UI object, an AndroidViewModel is probably where it should be kept if you want sounds to not be interrupted during screen rotations. If you want to encapsulate it from non-UI stuff, it can be in a separate ViewModel class.